Convert a column of dictionary datatype to table in kdb
I was trying to convert a column which has a dictionary datatype on a table to a separate table to fetch information from it easily. This works with a simple uj for me when the dictionaries have the same set of keys. E.g. is shown below, which gives me a table with column names x and y as each dictionary in the table had  two of the same keys.
q)t1:([] a:1 2 3 ; b: `a`b`c; d:(`x`y!(1 2); `x`y!(11 22); `x`y!(111 222)))
q){(uj/) value x }each select d from t1
x   y
-------
1   2
11  22
111 222

When I try and do this with a table which has a dictionary with different keys, shown below as 2 of these has keys x and y while the last one also has z in it. This would return me a kind of list of dictionaries rather than a table structure, how can I handle this?
q)t1:([] a:1 2 3 ; b: `a`b`c; d:(`x`y!(1 2); `x`y!(11 22); `x`y`z!(111 222 333)))
q){(uj/) value x }each select d from t1
`x`y!1 2
`x`y!11 22
`x`y`z!111 222 333
q)


See this recent answer for same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78922432/4256419

One method:
q)(uj/)enlist each exec d from t1
x   y   z
-----------
1   2
11  22
111 222 333

enlist each is converting each dictionary to a table and (uj/) will return a union of their columns.
FWIW, in this scenario exec d from t1 has the same output as {(uj/) value x }each select d from t1
q)(exec d from t1)~{(uj/) value x }each select d from t1
1b


Alternative method:
q)t1:([] a:1 2 3 ; b: `a`b`c; d:(`x`y!(1 2); `x`y!(11 22); `x`y`z!(111 222 333)))
q){(distinct raze key each x)#/:x} exec d from t1
x   y   z
-----------
1   2
11  22
111 222 333


Depending on order of keys and datatypes this will give you very mixed up results with respect to what nulls are chosen by # when you try to extract keys which are not in the dictionary. A way around this using a prototype dictionary outlined previously at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78922432/4256419

Questions like this one smack to me of 'wrong tool for the job'. KDB is good at querying/aggregating millions of rows of data. It's not good for this kind of thing.

Another approach using a more custom iterator
q)(){x uj enlist y}/t1`d
x   y   z
-----------
1   2
11  22
111 222 333

/or (same thing)
{x uj enlist y}/[();t1`d]

Ultimately the same as Cathals approach
